# AngularJS app not saving data in IE 9,10 and 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an application in AngularJS. We are about to launch it and QA just discovered that no data gets saved with IE versions 9,10 and 11. I see in network tab in console that the get request and post are sending the right data, but as soon as the user navigates away from the page and then goes back that data is no longer there. If the user logs out then logs back in the data displays correctly. In all other browsers there isn't any problem, only in IE 9,10 and 11.

Is there a plugin I need to be using to solve this? Anyone else ever have this problem and if so how to solve.

Comment: Can you post a small Plunkr demonstrating the problem? It's a problem with your code rather than a need for a plugin, so you will need to post your code.

Comment: We have no idea how your app is set up. Highly improbable that it is browser specific issue for it to happen across so many IE versions. Sounds more like logic or cache problem. Create demo that replicates issue

Comment: I can post the code, but no way to have a working code as the app is to large. But here is a plunker with html and the controller http://plnkr.co/edit/RA62LmRLFkVxUJSUYr82

Comment: Im sure this is just a cache issue with IE. Is there way to stop IE from cacheing the data?

Comment: Explain process flow in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with Internet Explorer cacheing all the get requests by installing this module:
[angular-cache-buster](https://github.com/saintmac/angular-cache-buster)

If anyone else has this issue its an easy fix!!!